# how to make app stretch to all phones android studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

so I'm making a really simple app that just shows some buttons and images, 
it looks great on the simulator (because I guess that's the resolution I've been working on ...)
but when I try to build it to my phone it looks differently (the buttons are more stretched out and there is allot more background space in between the buttons and the end of the screen,

I guess it's something that's suppose to be simple but how to I make my app "zoom stretch" to the phone content it's going to be on, meaning it will look the same on any phone and if necessary will stretch the image a bit to fit the screen ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, its important to not use specific(dp,px,etc.) sizes for laying buttons/text boxes/etc. out. For example, for a button thats on the page, use a "layout_width" of "match_parent" and add padding (if necessary from there). This will allow your button to stretch properly without having that extra whitespace.